# Eloquent relationships query building method returns empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a one-to-many relationship, which works perfectly when using the relationship as a property on a query, but when i try to use it as a method it always return empty.

**User Model**

```
public function reports()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Report', Report::COL_USER_ID, self::COL_ID);
}
```

**Report Model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User', User::COL_ID, self::COL_USER_ID);
}
```

**This Works**

```
$reports = User::find($id)->reports;
```

**This Doesn't and i need something like this**

```
$reports = User::find($id)->reports()->orderBy(Report::COL_CREATED_AT, self::ORDER_BY_DESC);
```

According to the eloquent doc, "since all relationships also serve as query builders, you can add further constraints", so that should totally be retrieving the proper data, am I missing something? Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `get` method to get actual results, so you should use:

```
$reports = User::find($id)->reports()->orderBy(Report::COL_CREATED_AT, self::ORDER_BY_DESC)->get();
```

instead of only:

```
$reports = User::find($id)->reports()->orderBy(Report::COL_CREATED_AT, self::ORDER_BY_DESC);
```

In your case, you only created query and haven't get any results from database. That's why you don't get any results.

And the reason why:

```
$reports = User::find($id)->reports;
```

works is because it's shortcut for:

```
$reports = User::find($id)->reports()->get();
```

If you try to use:

```
$reports = User::find($id)->reports();
```

only you won't get any results either.

Comment: thanks! had a feeling it was something ridiculous :/